# Is there a way to ask Emerge to "pick both"?

Tags: emerge

As far as I can see I only have the options to pick either A, or B, but not both. I occasionally want to pick both A and B. I know I can just go to the C buffer and edit the file by hand, but it happens often enough that I'd love a key for it. (A different conflict resolution tool I've used in the past, though I cannot remember which, allowed two options: A then B, and B then A.)

An example follows. Let's say I have the following conflict:

```
fi
fo
fa
fum
<<<<<<< HEAD
foo
=======
bar
>>>>>>> bar
I
like
Bubble
Gum
```

I would then like an option "A then B" that would yield the following result:

```
fi
fo
fa
fum
foo
bar
I
like
Bubble
Gum
```

As extra bonus, I'd love a "B then A" option that would yield the following result:

```
fi
fo
fa
fum
bar
foo
I
like
Bubble
Gum
```

PS: I usually invoke emerge from Magit. I'm not sure if this is relevant... Further, I'm on a Mac and I use Emacs 25 pre-test from http://emacsformacosx.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are commands `i a` and `i b` which insert a or b; or `x c` to combine using a template.

For your bonus case you should use `a` followed by `i b`.

You can find more about that [here](http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/emerge.html).

Comment: This does not work, I'm afraid. `a` (as expected) inputs `foo`, but when pressing `i b` this is replaced by `bar`: it does not combine the output. Further, `xc` to combine with a template results in a `x is undefined` message.

Comment: It does, if you really use `emerge`, as your question suggested. As far as I know `magit`, however, uses `smerge` or `ediff`. They do work differently. You may want to look [here](https://prometheansacrifice.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/using-emacs-as-git-mergetool/) for a hint how to use emerge to resolve conflicts.

Comment: Btw, the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656311/conflict-resolution-with-emacs-ediff-how-can-i-take-the-changes-of-both-version) may provide a way to solve that problem using `ediff`.

Comment: oh gosh, you're right -- I am actually using ediff! Very sorry about that! I'll create a new question to ask what I really had in mind...

Comment: theldoria thanks, that is exactly the kind of answer I am looking for. I can even get the AthenB / BthenA by swapping the buffers with `~`. Thanks a lot!